# Get the Values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the array structure as given below... Here I want to get the id value of all final child by dynamically because this array may have a lot of child. How I get id value of every final child by dynamically?
I want to values from below array structure like this

```
6
7
8
9
17

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 17
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the endpoints with recursion

```
function getIds($data){
    $out = array();
    if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $elm){
                    if($elm['children']){
                            $out = array_merge($out,getIds($elm['children']));
                    }else{
                            $out[] = $elm['id'];
                    }
            }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jesper....i got output exactly what i want...

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with recursion:

```
function get_final($arr) {
    $out = array();
    if(is_array($arr)) {
        foreach($arr as $a) {
            $out = array_merge($out, get_final($a));
        }
        return $out;
    }
    else return array($arr);
}
```

Comment: This function returns all id's not just the endpoints

Comment: Right, I thought that was what you wanted - all the non-array end points. Ah well, Jesper has already posted the same function but which only returns the deepest ids.

Comment: yes benubird...jesper function is working well...